# How to insert a value from a in another table via trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to create a trigger to insert a value in another table when a value is inserted in the first table.

So far my trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgIdPass
AFTER INSERT
ON tbuser FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE vIdPass INT
SET vIdPass = NEW.id
INSERT INTO tbpass.fkUser VALUES vIdPass
END
```

When I try to run the code, it gives this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET vIdPass = NEW.id INSERT INTO tbpass.fkUser VALUES vIdPass END' at line 8"

So anyone can illuminate my on why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon `;` after `DECLARE vIdPass INT`

Comment: There's no need for the variable. Just do `INSERT INTO tbpass.fkUser VALUES (NEW.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need `DELIMITERs` and statement terminators.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tgIdPass
AFTER INSERT
ON tbuser FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE vIdPass INT;  -- terminate statements
...
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```